# How to solve this Mystery with Mathematics

Tags: education

I read a mystery in a book but I can't solve it with Mathematics. The mystery is: 
"I have tripled my nephew's age, and 5 years ago I have 5 times from his twin brother age. What is my age now?" 
In mathematics the problem is like this: 
$x=$my age , $y=$my nephew's age 
$x=3y$
$x-5=5y$
but the answer from that equation is not true.
the correct answers are : $x=30$ and $y=10$. How did they solve this problem? 
(sorry for my bad english)

Comment: The second equations should be $x-5=5(y-5)$

Comment: Your age is $30$.

Comment: @Artem: Yes, that's it. The nephew was also 5 years younger then.

Comment: What does "I have 5 times from his twin brother age" mean?

Comment: Interesting that only copper.hat asked that needed question more than half hour after the OP was posted: what did people understand?!

Comment: Perhaps the riddle should be: "Right now I'm three times as old as my nephew is, and 5 years ago I was 5 times as old as his (the nephew's, apparently) twin brother was. What's my age now?"

Comment: It could be I am 5 times my twin's brother age... which could be older or younger.

Comment: @DonAntonio:Yes, it's true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints: using your notation, and assuming the riddle is what I wrote in the comment above, the equations are

$$\begin{align*}x&=3y\\(x-5)&=5(y-5)\end{align*}$$

Substitute the first eq. into the second one and get $\;y=10\;$ ...